# Count the number of times a value appears in a column using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, count

I have a dataframe `x` in R

```
ID Name Code
1  John aa1
1  Sue  aa2
1  Mike aa2
1  Karl aa3
1  Lucy aa1
```

I would like to add an extra column to this dataframe counting the number of times each `Code` value appears:

```
ID Name Code Code_frequency
1  John aa1  1
1  Sue  aa2  2
1  Mike aa2  2
1  Karl aa3  1
1  Lucy aa4  1
```

I've tried using various combinations of `mutate` and `count` but I get error messages saying that I've used the wrong data type: `no applicable method for 'count' applied to an object of class "character"`

I've also seen that dplyr has the `summarise` function but I need to preserve the layout of the dataframe as this will be exported from R as each row needs to be manually checked.

Is there a way to do this in R? A dplyr solution would fit easily into the rest of the code I have but I would welcome suggestions from other libraries as well.

Comment: Have you tried `x %>% group_by(Code) %>% mutate(Code_frequency= n())`

Comment: @HarrisonJones that seems to work - happy to mark it as the answer if you want to add it as one. One question though - does a grouped dataframe need to be ungrouped before it is grouped using another column?

Comment: I added `ungroup()` to my answer but you can just use `group_by()` again and it will reset the grouping on the data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `n()` function:

```
x %>%
  group_by(Code) %>%
  mutate(Code_frequency = n()) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably a simpler solution using dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(ID=rep(1,5), Name=c('John', 'Sue', 'Mike',"Karl",'Lucy'), Code=c('aa1', 'aa2','aa2','aa3','aa4'))
df
#   ID Name Code
# 1  1 John  aa1
# 2  1  Sue  aa2
# 3  1 Mike  aa2
# 4  1 Karl  aa3
# 5  1 Lucy  aa4

# for getting the frequency in a new column
df %>% add_count(Code, sort = FALSE, name= "Code_frequency")
#   ID Name Code Code_frequency
# 1  1 John  aa1              1
# 2  1  Sue  aa2              2
# 3  1 Mike  aa2              2
# 4  1 Karl  aa3              1
# 5  1 Lucy  aa4              1

# for just getting the frequency distribution
df %>% count(Code, sort = TRUE, name= "Code_frequency")
#   Code Code_frequency
# 1  aa2              2
# 2  aa1              1
# 3  aa3              1
# 4  aa4              1
```